# Self-test assessment for Ethereum vulnerabilities

Tags: solidity

A while ago I found a wonderful website, where one is presented a series of smart contracts with vulnerabilities, and then has to fix these. However, I cannot find this application anywhere anymore, does anyone know this website or something similar?

Comment: check if this useful  https://github.com/ConsenSys/smart-contract-best-practices/blob/master/docs/known_attacks.md

Comment: Please see Jaime's answer for the app I was referring too, although I also much appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that one, was really instructive, made by Zeppelin, you can find it here:

https://ethernaut.zeppelin.solutions/level/0xdf51a9e8ce57e7787e4a27dd19880fd7106b9a5c

Hope this helps